# Running Procs Off SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am pretty new to SSRS but what I have is a proc that executes a series of events that load data into a work table and based on the parameter it loads different data. I want to pass the parameter to the proc so the correct block of code is run. And then run the report off of the work table

I've been trying different ways to accomplish this but none is working. I set up the parameters with the values I want passed in and I keep getting an error message

> "Procedure p_TAT_Reports has no parameters and arguments were supplied"

Comment: Please post your stored procedure definition

Comment: Post what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this depending on what you need. If you just want to execute the proc and then follow it with a select statement you can use the following format:

```
exec MyProc @Parameter1, @Parameter2
```

If you just want to run the proc and it will return the dataset, you can use the following format, but you have to change the Command type to StoredProcedure in the Query Designer in Text mode:

```
MyProc @Parameter1, @Parameter2
```